# Accessing data in Google Sheets for fulfillment with Dialogflow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to create a custom Google action to turn on machines in a facility and log who is using them and for how long. How do I access Google sheets without using a service account?

So far, I've essentially just copy pasted from [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js). Specifically, lines 17, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, and 32. (I did also replace things like "client_email", which as far as I can tell will only work with a service account which I can't use for financial reasons.)

```
<code>
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google')
const {google} = require('googleapis')
const {WebHookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment')

const sheets = google.sheets('v4')

const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent'
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent'
const MACHINE_OFF_INTENT = 'Machine off'
const MACHINE_ON_INTENT = 'Machine on'
const MACHINE_TYPE_ENTITY = 'machine'
const MEMBER_NUM_ENTITY = 'number-sequence'


const app = dialogflow()

app.intent(FALLBACK_INTENT, (conv) => {
 conv.ask("I didn't understand your request")
})

app.intent(MACHINE_OFF_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const machine_type = conv.parameters[MACHINE_TYPE_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
    const member_number = conv.parameters[MEMBER_NUM_ENTITY];
  const spreadsheetID =  "1n5VTSy5e8ger8FeKvKXymFMf2DGLK2lAKe_Qw2iG7Vc";
  const appl = SpreadsheetApp;
  const ss = appl.openById(spreadsheetID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Authorizations");
  var engraverAuth = sheet.getRange("A1:A100");
  var woodshopAuth = sheet.getRange("B1:B100");
  var metalshopAuth = sheet.getRange("C1:C100");
  var allAuth = sheet.getRange("D1:D100");
  switch(machine_type){
        case "laser engraver":
        if (member_number.constructor == engraverAuth || member_number.constructor == allAuth) {

        }
      else {
       conv.ask("You are not authorized to use that machine"); 
      }
        break;
        case "woodshop":
          if (member_number.constructor ==woodshopAuth || member_number.constructor == allAuth) {

          }
            else {
       conv.ask("You are not authorized to use that machine"); 
      }
          break;
        case "metalshop":
          if (member_number.constructor ==metalshopAuth || member_number.constructor == allAuth) {

          }
            else {
       conv.ask("You are not authorized to use that machine");
      }
          break;
        default:

      }
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
</code>
```

It just outputs error 500 (internal server error) which I guess is because I'm not authorizing it to use sheets? I'm new to all this and learning as I go so I'm certain there are several fundamental flaws going on here that would be obvious to most people, so help of any kind is appreciated.